# Post json data to REST service using android/httpclient with stream

Tags: android, json, http, rest

I am having some difficulty POSTing data to my REST WCF service. I need to send a json object/array to it, but my POST methods are expecting a Stream which is then picked apart to get the JSON (can't change this part).

I have accomplished this in C# with this code:

```
    public static string CallPostService(string url, string data)
    {
        url = Config.serviceAddress + url;
        string json = data;
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            sw.Write(json);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string res = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return res;
        }
    }
```

I need some equivalent Java code to do this, preferably using the Apache HttpClient. I am new to http libraries so I would appreciate a little direction.

EDITS:

Here is a method header from my WCF service. The request body needs to be a stream so the service can handle it.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "person/delete", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Person DeletePerson(Stream streamdata) { //bla }
```

Comment: how far have you gone using java?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but I have actually been able to perform GETs with the HttpClient, just need to get POST working.

Comment: post works the same way, you just need to give it an entity (which can be a lot of different things)

Comment: No, not when the method is expecting a Stream. Thats the key, the stream. My service methods are not simply expecting a json object, (i.e "application/json" content-type) they are expecting a Stream ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Comment: This is probably what InputStreamEntity is for

Comment: also, it doesn't really _need_ to be a stream. a stream is just a list of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

check this code snippet.
I dint really tried it, but it should work

```
public void postData() {
try {    
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
(username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"), 
android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP
 );
 httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ auth);

    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

Comment: That is not going to work. You are not sending a stream as the request body. I will post a WCF method for clarification.

Comment: Open HTTP Connection and POST string

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to do, but I don't know a way of sending it as a STREAM..

Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
      String MyData;// Data need to post to server JSON/XML
      String reply;  
      try {

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 
        HttpURLConnection httppost = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        httppost.setDoInput(true); 
        httppost.setDoOutput(true); 
        httppost.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        httppost.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "UA Here"); 
        httppost.setRequestProperty("Accept_Language", "en-US"); 
        httppost.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "content type here"); 
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(httppost.getOutputStream()); 
        dos.write(MyData.getBytes()); // bytes[] b of post data 

        InputStream in = httppost.getInputStream(); 
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
        try { 
            int chr; 
            while ((chr = in.read()) != -1) { 
                sb.append((char) chr); 
            } 
            reply = sb.toString(); 
        } finally { 
            in.close(); 
        } 

        Log.v("POST RESPONSE",reply);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, I am confused about a couple variables you have their though. What type is 'urls' and 'reply'.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with http client? I have to do NTLM authentication and I have custom socketfactories and schemefactories for doing that. Either that or some way to use those with the HttpURLConnection.

Comment: how can i send special characters using this one?
I tried to use this which did help me connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(strJsonRequest.toString().getBytes().length));